# Problems with cx_Freeze - ImportError

Tags: python, qt, pyside, packaging, cx-freeze

I'm trying to freeze application written in python (PySide), Qt. I'm using LMDE, and in Windows application runs, but have problems with Linux.

When I try it at another computer with same version of Mint Debian it doesn't start, and when I try to start it in terminal, it pops:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "start.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/alexdeb/Desktop/AlexW/EXE_Start.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_PySide_QtCore.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: libpyside-python2.7.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any help, please?

Comment: It can't find the pyside lib. On windows, cx_freeze copy the dll to the build folder. Check if on linux it does the same. If not, it seems that the target PC must have pyside installed.

Answer (score 0):

Run the application using *strace* to find out which object file it's trying to load